# innerText not preserving line breaks

Tags: javascript, escaping, innerhtml, innertext

I am trying to remove HTML tags from a string, but I want to remove line breaks. The code below doesn't work, and so far, I haven't found a regex solutions that works.

```js
let input = "First<br>Second"
let cleaned = document.createElement("pre");
cleaned.innerHTML = input;
let output = cleaned.innerText;
console.log(output);
```

What I want: "First\nSecond"

What it returns: "FirstSecond"

How do I fix this?

Comment: I guess it depends on which browser you use, in Safari the line break is preserved, but not Firefox, Opera or Chrome. I think this is a throwback to the browser wars, when Microsoft invented innerText and the W3C came up with textContent. They worked a little differently, which has persisted to this day, and Firefox's Mozilla/Netscape roots seems to mean it implements textContent for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

```js
let input = "First<br>Second"
let output = input.replace("<br>", "\\n");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This is close, but the input might have other tags like `<p>` and `<span>`.

Comment: I already suggested this, and it works. You said you wanted to remove the <br> tag, insert a newline character, and output it to the console. Why are you mentioning other tags? Do you want to handle those also?

Comment: @user12976477, will this work then?
`let input = "First<br>Second"`
then
`let output = input.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "/n");`

Comment: @Jy T Yes! That's the first regex that works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You say you havent gotten any regex to work, have you tried this?

```
cleaned.innerHTML = input.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
```

Comment: [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: innerHTML does not display but innerText displays in my browser